# SweetAlert : 2nd argument ('undefined') is invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sweetalert

I'm using php, jquery, ajax to design and develop my website. The problem is on a page where I want to insert a record through ajax & php using sweet alerts. I want the user to press yes button of sweet alert to execute the inserting php. When I checked the console once the record was not inserted it gave me an error.

My project is locally designed that's why I had not used a cdn. Instead all of the javacript and css files are in my project directory. I have not imported them, rather I pasted the cdn url instead in the search box and copy/paste what came out. Same goes with sweet alerts.

This is the ajax and sweet alert code:

```
swal("", "Do you really want to create this project?", "warning", {
      buttons : {
             confirm : "Yes",
             cancel : "No"
                 }
      })
        .then((value) => {
           switch (value) {
               case true :
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "customer.php",
                       data: {"Name":name, "Descpt":descpt, "Category":category, "Skills":skills},
                       dataType: 'JSON',
                       success: function(feedback) {
                          if (feedback.status === "success")
                          {
                            swal("", feedback.message, "success", {buttons : false});
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            swal("Fatal error occurred", feedback.message, "error", {buttons : false});
                          }
                       },
                       error: function(feedback) {
                          swal("Fatal error occurred", feedback.message, "error", {buttons : false});
                                  }
                         });
                         break;                                
                  }
        });
```

This is the error its giving me:

`Uncaught SweetAlert: 2nd argument ('undefined') is invalid`

Their is another form as well where I have performed the same action by inserting a record only when user press yes on sweet alert and it worked perfectly. I don't know what this error is. I even copied and pasted the sweet alert code I earlier use in another page where it was working but still it arises the same error.

Well after tracking the sweet alert file I found the line where it was actually giving me the problem:

```
e.throwErr = function(t) {
            throw t = t.replace(/ +(?= )/g, ""),
            "SweetAlert: " + (t = t.trim())
        }
```

I can also show you the could that is perfectly working for me. Hope you can spot the difference:

```
swal("Registering Without Email", "Are you sure that you want to register your account without providing the email?", "warning", {
                    buttons : {
                        confirm : "Yes",
                        cancel : "No"
                    }
                })
                .then((value) => {
                    switch (value) {
                        case true :
                                workEmail = "no email";
                                $.ajax({
                                    type : "POST",
                                    url : "register_worker.php",
                                    data : {"name":workName, "email":workEmail, 'password':workPassword, "contact":workPhone, "address":workAddress, "nic":workNic},
                                    dataType : 'JSON',
                                    success : function(feedback) {
                                        if (feedback.status === "success")
                                        {
                                            window.location = "/Dashboard";
                                        }
                                        else if (feedback.status === "error")
                                        {
                                            swal("", feedback.message, "error");
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            alert('error occurred ' + feedback.message);
                                        }
                                    },
                                    error : function(feedback) {
                                        alert ('Unknown error occurred ' + feedback.message);
                                    }
                                });
                                break;                                
                    }
                });
```

Please help...

Comment: Use `console.log(feedback)` to see what that object contains; that's probably the problem, because in three places you pass `feedback.message` to `swal()`.

Comment: _“I found the line where it was actually giving me the problem”_ - nah, that looks like part of the script that does some formatting on error messages before showing them, but not like the place where the error actually occurred …

Comment: actually its not giving any messages. Its not even executing the succes or error function. How am I supposed to check the error then. Please tell...

Comment: I'm wondering if this is supported syntax with sweet alert. I've used it a lot, and I've never passed parameters like that, nor can I find it in the documentation. So two things: I know you can pass three arguments to a swal function, like 
`swal(title, message, messageType)`. And I know you can have a lot more configurations, but then you pass one setup object, and one function. Are you sure the syntax you are using is valid? Are you using Sweet Alert, or Sweet Alert 2?

Comment: @KjetilNordin I have mentioned that this script with exactly the same swal function is perfectly working for another php file. All the problems are arising with this one.

Comment: Is it sweet alert or sweet alert 2?

Comment: When I try this, using sweet alert (not 2) it simply disregards the fourth parameter passed. It shows a message, but only with an OK-button, and nothing else. And the function returns nothing, so I get an error  that i cannot call `then` on undefined. Which makes me think it might be sweet alert 2 you're using, and mentioning that in the title of the question, or the tags, will give you a higher chance of getting the help you need.

Comment: @KjetilNordin
See this code:

`swal("Registering Without Email", "Are you sure that you want to register your account without providing the email?", "warning", {
                    buttons : {
                        confirm : "Yes",
                        cancel : "No"
                    }
                })`


This is the code perfectly working for me. Tell me if you find difference between then. Ignore the code from `.then((value) => {--- some code ---});` it is also the same

Comment: I suspect that the code you have posted is actually not causing any of your problems. I think what the server returns is the problem, like I've written in my answer, so we need to see the content of the feedback object.

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely thrown from the swal function inside the promise. The feedback.message is not set, which will cause sweet alert to complain that 'undefined' is not a valid parameter for the message body.

There is nothing wrong with your code, except expecting to get something from server side, that you do not get.

Comment: okay that can be a issue. Only if it returns the success or error function. Their is no error in my php file which is suppose to insert the record and then return a feedback message. But my php script is not running as well.

Comment: Have a look at @Pointy's comment to the original question. insert the line `console.log(feedback)` right after `success : function(feedback) {` and let us know what the console says. This will provide you and us with more information.

Answer (score -1):

finally i got where was the error.  I'm not able to select the value from select box. First here's the html code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="cateogry" name="category">
                  <option value="0" disabled selected>Choose Project Category</option>
                  <option value="active">Active Project</option>
                  <option value="drafted">Drafted Project</option>
</select>
```

Now these are the js / jquery codes i have tried but getting nothing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         //First thing i tried
         var category = $('#category').val();

         //Second thing i tried
         var category = $('#category').filter(":selected").val();

         //Third thing i tried
         var category = $('#category').find(":selected").text();

         //Fourth thing i tried
         var category = $('#category').find(":selected").val();
});
```

But still no success please tell me what should I do.

Comment: Good job continuing to explore and add info. It would be better to update the question with this info though, since it is not actually an answer. Here, your error might be that the id of your select is misspelled as `cateogry`instead of `category`. But without any other info, it is very hard for me to link this to your original question. Your explanations are a little bit all over the place.

Comment: Also, you keep asking for help, but you do not actually try to answer some of the questions from people trying to help you. So I will try one more time. Let us know what console.log(feedback) results to in the console. And tell us if you are using sweet alert, or sweet alert 2. These things can be very important for us to help you further.